# libpq error: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00

Tags: boost, boost-asio, endianness, libpq, libpqxx

I am trying to insert values to a postgresql table using libpq (in Binary Format).

Below is my query

> insert into  client_data (serverid,ipaddress,portid) values ($1,$2,$3)

The data type for table fields are as follows

```
serverid -> smallint (INT2OID)  
ipaddress  -> varchar (VARCHAROID)  
portid -> integer (INT4OID)
```

When I'm executing PQexecParams(), I am getting below error (from PQerrorMessage())

> ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00

On debugging I found that paramValues for portid is getting error, which is as below

```
    int val = boost::endian::native_to_big(1); 
    paramValues[3] = (char*)&val; // here is the possible issue
```

when I'm casting address of val to char pointer and  the value pointed by char pointer is evaluated as NULL.

What could be the solution?
one way is to insert data as char* and setting ParamFormats to 0 for all.

Comment: Don't use binary format unless you really, absolutely, definitely need to.

Comment: Please show the exact invocation of `PQexecParams` - you're ommiting the crucial paramFormats array.

Answer (score 1):

It's my bad. For ipaddress I was passing wrong paramLenghth.  I am reading paramaters values from different buffer and insread of passing strlen(ipaddress), I was passinh size of buffer.